# Make a spider to download only specific pages

Tags: web-crawler, scrapy

need help from someone have experience with scrapy & python. How can I configure spider to  dowload only pages witch  contains some words (in body of the page)?

Comment: Your question does not make sense. How can you know if a page contains specific words without downloading it?

Answer (score 0):

Scrapy provides a way to filter out contents using an [Item Pipeline](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html), you can write a custom pipeline and make it drop all content that does not have the words you are looking for. You can see an example here.